# How to structure CMake project into smaller projects?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

:)

My current project structure looks something like this:

```
MyProject
|_ CMakeLists.txt   
|_ src
  |_ CMakeLists.txt
  |_ clazz.cpp
  |_ clazz.h
  |_ magic.cpp
  |_ magic.h
|_ test
  |_ CMakeLists.txt
```

Now the src directory has been growing and growing, containing 15+ files. Inside my IDE (Qt-Creator) I see all of those files listed underneath each other which doesn't help at keeping a good overview. Qt-Creator groups them by project and this far, there is only one.

The root CMakeLists.txt reads:

```
project(myproject)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

And the one inside src is something like:

```
set(SRCS clazz.cpp, magic.cpp)
set(INCS clazz.h, magic.h)
add_library(mypro STATIC ${SRCS} ${INCS})
target_include_directories(mypro PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

How'd you structure this project into kind of "subprojects" with CMake? Simply creating subdirectories won't do the trick here.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Complicating your CMAKE structure just to make your IDE happy seems like a bad choice. I would look into making Qt-Creator list your files dirrefently.

Comment: Do you mean just making a `project(magic)` inside of `src`? Because that's how I've always done it. And then your `myproject` solution would contain all of them. However, it's important that you get your dependencies correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yeah, creating multiple projects came to my mind as well. No idea if that's a good way to do it though.

Comment: Maybe modularize your applicatio? Also, public header should not be added into library sources, but into the `PUBLIC_HEADER` target property